# Flask, MongoEngine, WTForms - errors on form rendering

Tags: flask, mongoengine, wtforms

I have the following model:

```
class Post(Document):
    body = db.StringField(required=True)
    author = db.StringField(verbose_name="Author", max_length=255, required=True)
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)
    comments = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Comment'))
```

and the follwing view:

```
from flask.ext.mongoengine.wtf import model_form

@app.route('/')
def home():
    form = model_form(Post, exclude=('created_at', 'comments'))
    return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

I don't know how to render this form in template. I did try couple things:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

This gives the following error:

```
TypeError: 'FormMeta' object is not iterable
```

Also I tried this:

```
{{ form.body() }}
```

With different error:

```
AttributeError: 'UnboundField' object has no attribute '__call__'
```

and {{ form.body }} renders like this

```
<UnboundField(TextAreaField, (), {'default': None, 'validators': [<wtforms.validators.Required object at 0x7f63804d0fd0>], 'description': '', 'filters': [], 'label': None})>
```

Comment: Does `{{ field() }}` throw an error?  Also what versions of wtf / flask / mongoengine

Comment: this code fails before this statement, {% for field in form %}{% endfor %} does the same thing

Comment: Flask==0.10.1
pymongo==2.6
mongoengine==0.8.4
WTForms==1.0.4
Flask-WTF==0.9.1
flask-mongoengine==0.7.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initiate the form:

```
from flask.ext.mongoengine.wtf import model_form

@app.route('/')
def home():
    form = model_form(Post, exclude=('created_at', 'comments'))(request.form)
    return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

An example project using the same stack can be found: https://github.com/rozza/flask-tumblelog

Comment: Thanks this works. Do you know why it converts db.StringField automatically to TextArea input?

Comment: @Bitmap I find this rather odd also

Answer (score 0):

Form is not iterable. It is mentioned in the error.

I haven't used model_form, but I think `{{ form.field_name }}` should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: According to documentation (http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.4/forms.html) and all examples I've seen it is itarable. {{ form.body }} renders like this "<UnboundField(TextAreaField, (), {'default': None, 'validators': [<wtforms.validators.Required object at 0x7f63804d0fd0>], 'description': '', 'filters': [], 'label': None})>"